# dynamically import compiled .pyc pasted to library.zip

Tags: python, python-import

When I run the compiled exe of my program, is it possible to paste a compiled .pyc file in  the library and dynamically import it with out re-opening my .exe?

It seem's that when you run the exe, all the imported modules are saved at the computers memory. So even if the imported module in library is deleted, it will not raise an error.

thanks.

Comment: Is the [`reload`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) built-in function what you are looking for?  What problem are you solving that you need to alter the zip file?

Comment: you can add the location of the library to the beginning of `sys.path` inside your exe so that it will look for imports there (of coarse this would mean you would have to know where you were adding it (or use `os.getcwd()`). also you would obviously need to change your code and rebuild your exe